# Eclipse Plugin : How to convert "java. lang. string" into IEditorInput?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Eclipse Plugin

I want the editor to open a source code. I only have one string(java.lang.String). How do I do that?

Comment: You will need to use `IStorageEditorInput`. There isn't a standard implementation for a String - but there is an example [here](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/06/opening-editor-without-ifile.html)

Comment: I want the editor to open the java. lang. String source code file ,  instead of a custom string

Comment: It's like clicking the StackTraceElement link in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to open the class file editor for the `java.lang.String` class (which will open the source if it can be found). You would do something like:

```java
IProject project = ... java project you are interested in

// Get the JavaModel project
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);

// Find the String type using the classpath defined in the project
IType stringType = javaProject.findType("java.lang.String");

// Find the class file
IJavaElement classFile = stringType.getAncestor(IJavaElement.CLASS_FILE);

// Open the editor
JavaUI.openInEditor(classFile);
```